# Server Not Displaying POST Data

Tags: android, node.js, express, android-volley

I used this code to send POST data (a JSON object) to my Node/Express.js server. I used body-parser, and the server receives data from StringRequests without a problem, but when I send a JsonArrayRequest, the output of console.log(request.body); is '{}'.

RequestBin received the POST data and displayed it correctly, though.

I tried adding content-type: application/json to the header of the POST request using a HashMap as was recommended to another person with a similar problem, but that didn't work for me. It still doesn't show.

All I used was body-parser and the Express plugin with Node.js 0.12. Any ideas?

```
public void SearchFor(final String placetype, final String placelocation) throws JSONException {
        String url = "http://requestb.in/113ewl01";
        JSONObject PlaceObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray PlJarr = new JSONArray();
        PlaceObj.put("PlaceType", placetype);
        PlaceObj.put("PlaceLocation", placelocation);

        //PlJarr.put(PlaceObj);
        RequestQueue PlaceQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonArrayRequest PlaceArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, PlJarr, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int i;
                ArrayList<String> MArrList = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> PlaceList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        MArrList.add(response.get(i).toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                JSONObject PlaceParser = null;
                try {
                    for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        PlaceParser = new JSONObject(MArrList.get(i));
                        PlaceList.add(PlaceParser.get("PlaceName").toString() + "\n" + "Estimated Price: $" + PlaceParser.get("EstimatedPrice").toString() + ".\n" + PlaceParser.get("PlaceAddress").toString() + "\n" + PlaceParser.get("OtherDetails").toString());
                        hybridlist[i] = "$" + PlaceParser.get("EstimatedPrice").toString() + " - " + PlaceParser.get("PlaceName").toString();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DisplayHotels(PlaceList);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Toast VerrorToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Connection failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                VerrorToast.show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> HeadMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                HeadMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                HeadMap.put("charset", "utf-8");
                return HeadMap;
            }

        };

        PlaceQueue.add(PlaceArrayRequest);
    }
```

That RequestBin url has probably expired by now, though.

Thanks.

EDIT - I updated the code above. I just put my JSONObject into a JSONArray and sent the JSONArray instead, and added headers using a HashMap, but the server prints the same '{}'.

Here is a screenshot of what RequestBin received from the app:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rhpead&s=8#.ViWhon6rSM8

Comment: You are sending a `JSONObject` in a `JSONArray` request. You need to send an array of `JSONObject`'s

Comment: @AndrewBreen I changed it to a JSONArray, but the same thing happened. :(